# Is there any way I can manually set the intercept in SPSS?

Tags: correlation, spss, goodness-of-fit

As part of my dissertation I am looking into the relationship between temperature and methane emissions. A large proportion of this work relies on statistical interpretation and analysis. When plotting the link between flux and temperature SPSS outputted a 'quadratic' line of best fit with very little variation from the original linear plot. This doesn't fit the expected trend, however when I select the option to suppress the intercept the line of best fit follows the expected trend far better. A [previous thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11064/why-would-one-suppress-the-intercept-in-linear-regression) here pointed out some issues with this technique though.

If I chose to suppress the intercept it makes the assumption at temperature 0, flux is also 0 which is not the case. I was wondering if there was a way to 'suppress' the intercept as it were in order to maintain the improved line of best fit, but manually set the intercept to -5 for example.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not a good thing to do unless you have substantive (that is, not statistical) reason to be sure that the intercept should be -5. From your post, it doesn't sound like this is the case. The fact that the curve is not as expected is not necessarily a reason to change the basic regression set up.

However, if you still want to do this, you could do so by adding a constant to all values of the dependent variable and then setting the intercept to 0; this is equivalent to setting the intercept to the -1*that constant.

Comment: The reason I want to buffer the curve to intercept at negative 5 is due to the fact this is the temperature that methane flux terminates in both the data I have and also the value in a number of papers which investigated this in lab/field tests.

Thanks for the advice though, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, if you don't want to be bothered figuring out how to adjust the data and you have the Advanced Statistics option, you can just impose a constraint on the intercept by using CNLR.  For example,

MODEL PROGRAM  a=10000 b=1000 c=1000.

COMPUTE  PRED_=a + b*educ + c* jobtime.

CNLR salary
  /PRED PRED_
  /BOUNDS a=100000.

The BOUNDS subcommand specifies a specific value or range for selected parameters.